# Overflow: hidden not working on flex display

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've been experimenting with integrating something like this [star rating script](https://codepen.io/filcp/pen/QvZVOg) in to my Laravel app, and copy/pasted the relevant code. It works fine except the `overflow: hidden` property on the `front-stars` class isn't working as expected. Instead of being hidden, they just display below the rest.

This works fine when tested on CodePen, but it seems that something else perhaps interferes with this on my own page. What could be causing this to happen?

[My code on Codepen](https://codepen.io/LetsPrint3D/pen/GRRPMgj)

[image]

```
<style>
%flex-display {
    display: flex;
}
.back-stars {
    @extend %flex-display;
    color: #000;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.star-rating {
    @extend %flex-display;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    justify-content: center;
}
.front-stars {
    @extend %flex-display;
    color: #FFBC0B;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #d29b09;
    top: 0;
    transition: all .5s
}
</style>

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Info</div>
                    <div class="card-body">

                    <table id="dtInfo" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">Title</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Software</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Machine</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Rating</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Author</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            @foreach ($profiles as $profile)
                                <tr>
                                    <td><a href="{{ route('profile.show', $profile->id) }}">{{ $profile->title }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $profile->slicer }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $profile->machine }}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="star-rating" title="{{$profile->averageRating()}}">
                                            <div class="back-stars">
                                                <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>

                                                <div class="front-stars" style="width: {{$profile->ratingPercent()}}%">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>Username</td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: it's okay to share where you took it from, but also share your code where the bug lives, it's easier to investigate, a codepen with your rendered html and css perhaps ? (without the laravel syntax if possible)

Comment: Yes, please add codepen, or jsfiidle etc.

Comment: @Towkir Will do now, sorry!

Comment: @Towkir Added the codepen link, thanks

Comment: @AidanKnight, may I ask why you have a separate parent class for back and front stars? If your objective is to fill the empty stars with a filled one, wouldn't it be much easier if you changed its class?

Comment: why is `.font-stars` having a width of `50%` ? try to limit it's height to some `px` value, such as `20px`. that wiay, overflow hidden should work, now it does not have any height and contains all the elements inside it

Comment: @dwrellin I was just going based on that example codepen script I linked in the original post. His worked fine so I decided to start with it and go from there. I'm trying to get more familiar with CSS so this is a bunch of practice right now

Comment: @Towkir I believe he used the width of .front-stars to control how much of it overlays .back-stars, where width is working as a percentage of what is shown.

Comment: @Towkir Setting height worked. No idea why the source script didn't have to specify it, guess it was his exact font size settings and what not worked out that way, but that will be good enough. Thank you!

Comment: @AidanKnight, ohh, I see. I'm sorry I overlooked the link you sent. Glad you made it work thanks to Towkir. :)

Comment: should I post it as an answer then ? so that you can accept an upvote that ? :p

Comment: @towkir Please do, that would be appreciated :)

Comment: @dwrellin No problem, I realize my op was kind of erratic and perhaps not all that easy to follow lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your target element `.front-stars` is absolutely positioned and it has no height specified, overflow does not really work there.

You need to provide a specific height where the element should stop and hide the overflown elements. That's how overflow works,

According to your codepen:

```
.front-stars {
    @extend %flex-display;
    color: #FFBC0B;
    width: 50%;
    height: 24px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transition: all .5s
}
```

Also, try to reduce the darkness from the stars, so that it may look a bit nicer.

Learn more about how overflow works [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)